# Thunderbird app not opening when clicking on the notification in the action centre

Tags: windows-10, thunderbird, notifications

After having received an email via Thunderbird, a notification is left in the windows' native Action Centre. When clicked, I'm expecting it to open Thunderbird. However, nothing happens.

Is this an issue with my configuration, with the Thunderbird or with the OS?
Other apps are opened fine when doing this.

Windows 10 Pro 22H2 19045.3324
Thunderbird 115.2.0 (64-bit)
Thunderbird is allowed notifications and notification bubbles, priority Normal
Thunderbird is the default mail and mailto app

Edit:
When using the built-in notification system, clicking on the bubble itself brings up the app, as expected, but clicking on the notification in the Action Centre still brings up nothing

Answer (score 0):

In Thunderbird Settings, General options, "When new message arrive:" are system notifications used, or Thunderbird's own notifications? Toggling that setting might help.

[image: When New Messages Arrive]

Also, consider using sounds and tray icon, rather than *alert*, if the notification gets in the way.

Comment: System notifications are used, but intentionally so, and I expected that functionality from them.